# Bower Tunnelling error in corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli, bower-install

I am trying to setup new Ember application using ember-cli but getting this error even after updating proxies in "C:...\bower\node_modules\bower-config\lib\util\defaults.js"

> Installed packages for tooling via npm.
>   Error creating new application. Removing generated directory `./ember-quickstart`
>   
>   Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ember-cli-shims failed: tunnelin
>   g socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:S
>   SL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
>
> Error: Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ember-cli-shims failed: t
>   unneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140
>   770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.
>   c:794:
>
> at createError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\no
>   de_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\util\createError.js:
>   2:15)
>      at Request._callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-
>   cli\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\bower-registry-client\lib\lookup.js:97:2
>   9)
>      at self.callback (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\
>   node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\request\request.js:198:22)
>      at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>      at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
>     at Request.request.emit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\emb
>   er-cli\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\request-replay\index.js:89:29)
>      at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\e
>   mber-cli\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\request\request.js:820:8)
>     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\em
>   ber-cli\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:178:21)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [ember-cli-windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/ember-cli-windows) might help

Comment: @Kitler Can you explain how..

Comment: I can't I don't use windows.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `bower` cannot access to the bower repository. You have to setup proxies in `.bowerrc`.

Please check ~/.bowerrc in your home folder.

```
{
  "proxy": "http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
  "https-proxy":"http://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>",
  "strict-ssl": false,
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com/",
  "color": true 
}
```

The `strict-ssl: false` is turning off the usage of ssl. Maybe you need this also, depend of the firewall.

Comment: I tried this one also but still getting the same error

Comment: I added registry property also. Check out with this settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved running these two commands:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://user:password@host:portnumber"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://user:password@host:portnumber"
```

Replace `user`, `password`, `host` and `portnumber` with the ones of your proxy.